Bash script to uncomment lines with leading spaces on a file with specific pattern
I try to uncomment specific lines from a file with patterns in oracle linux 8.6 using bash. There are leading white spaces on certain lines where the comments are not removed. I tried to uncomment the commented lines with sed and grep for matching the patterns. I need to exactly match two numbers from the output. There is one word per column(total 2 columns) in the file each with numbers.
Example: column1:pd19_ORA column2:svg38.
I need to uncomment lines inplace with exact match of 19 and 38 without 190,1900 or 019 etc.. excluding lines such as,
   #pd19_ORA svg37 
#pd199_ORA svg388 

Code:
sed -n '/\<19\>/,+1p' cmfile|grep '38'|sed -i '/38/s/^#//g' cmfile

Contents of file:
    #pd19_ORA svg38
#pd19_ORA sil38
#pd29_ORA sil37
    

First line is still commented after using sed with inplace but comment of second line is removed.
Output:
    #pd19_ORA svg38
pd19_ORA sil38
#pd29_ORA sil37

How to remove the first line comment which has leading white spaces without removing the leading space?
Expected output:
    pd19_ORA svg38
pd19_ORA sil38
#pd29_ORA sil37


Sorry, I'm not quite understanding. You've asked how to remove a comment character from a line with leading whitespace - that's ok. But why is the second line uncommented when the third is not?

Or is it that you're actually trying to remove comments from lines containing 19 while still preserving leading whitespace?

@ChrisDavies the third line would not match the grep '38'.

@EduardoTrápani yes, that too. It's a bit confusing

It doesn't make sense to pipe to sed -i. When sed is operating in inplace mode, it ignores its standard input.

In your first sed command you use word boundaries around 19 but in your second one you don't use them around 38. Do you need word boundaries anywhere or is it OK to match on, say,  319 and 4387?

@EdMorton I need to exactly match patterns 19 and 38 without matching any other numbers.

@Kishan then why are you matching svg38 and sil38? Those are not exact matches of 38.  So would svg138 also be OK? Do you just want words that end with 38 or 19? Please [edit] your question and give us an example input and the output you would want from that example, but make the example more detailed. Include more lines that should be uncommented and more lines that should remain commented so we can understand what you need.

I think you're looking to remove a leading # character from all lines containing the number 19, while maintaining any leading whitespace
sed -E '/[^0-9]19([^0-9]|$)/s/^([[:space:]]*)#/\1/' cmfile

This searches for lines containing 19 (but without digits either side such as 019 or 193) since I couldn't get \<19\> to match any of your lines here.
In the case where you want lines containing 19 and 38 you simply need to extend the initial line matching:
sed -E '/[^0-9]19[^0-9](.*[^0-9]|)38([^0-9]|$)/s/^([[:space:]]*)#/\1/' cmfile

In both cases, for all such matched lines we capture any leading space preceding a # character so that we can add it back into the output.
Finally, as yet another variation, sed -i ... can be used to update the file seemingly in place

i need to filter two patterns one with 19 and other with 38 in single command and then uncomment the line.

What do you mean "filter two patterns"? You want a 19 and a 38 on the same line?

there are two strings each line, one with pd_ORA and second word with string. I want to grep or filter (with any alterative) numbers from both strings with 19 and 38 to make sure that i dont edit any other lines which has 19 with 37 etc..

So you want lines with both 19 and 38 in them?

Can i also edit the file inplace on the same sed command in one go without two separate commands?

@Kishan yes of course. You've already used sed -i in your question, and other answers have also used - and explained - what it does and does not do

sed -i is not working similar to sed -E with above regex code. Getting the error sed: -e expression #1, char 61: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

@Kishan you need the -E to handle the Extended Regular Expressions that I'm using. And if you want to edit in place then you also need the -i flag. From your description it sounds like you removed the -E and replaced it with -i..?

You can try awk and command like this can do the work. If you need to have the specific strings 19 and 38 on specific places you should mention it in question:
awk '/19/ && /38/ {sub(/#/,"")}1' 

This command search for line with 19 and 38 and remove the # symbol. And then print the line (independently if it's match and edited or not)
awk '/19/ && /38/ {sub(/#/,"")}1' input_file
    pd19_ORA svg38
pd19_ORA sil38
#pd29_ORA sil37

If you want to be sure # is the first nonwhite space symbol in the line you can modify the script like this:
 awk '/19/ && /38/ && $1 ~ "^#" {sub(/#/,"")}1' input_file

Here is changed script which search for specific strings, congaing desired numbers:
awk '$1~/pd19_ORA$/ && $2~/[a-z]{3}38$/ && $1 ~ "^#" {sub(/#/,"")}1' 


how to edit it inplace with awk?

@Kishan, you can do it with GNU gawk -i inplace '.......'

@RomeoNinov, beware gawk -i inplace is unsafe.

ITYM sub() rather than gsub() here.

@StéphaneChazelas, in my cygwin both work on the same way

gsub() replaces all occurrences of # while here, you likely want to replace only the first occurrence on each line.

"This command search for line with 19 and 38" - it would also match on the single instance of 1938, or substrings of numbers such as 219 or 5387

@ChrisDavies, true. I expect OP to clarify such conditions.

@RomeoNinov I updated the question with more details. gawk works fine on few linux variants but having platform specific bug issues.

@Kishan then you need to tell us what operating systems this needs to work on in the question.

@Kishan, you constantly change the question, it's like moving target. And you can't expect we change constantly the answers! Is it first string you search for EXACTLY pd19_ORA and is it second one [a-z]{3}38?

@Kishan, check my edited question

Assuming you want to uncomment the lines that contain 38 and that follow a line that contain a word-delimited¹ 19 as your attempt suggests you might want to do:
perl -pi -e 's/^\s*\K#// if $flag && /38/; $flag = /\b19\b/' your-file

In your:

sed -n '/\<19\>/,+1p' cmfile|grep '38'|sed -i '/38/s/^#//g' cmfile


The sed -i '/38/s/^#//g' cmfile command doesn't read its input, it only edits cmfile in place, removing a leading # on any line that contains 38 (btw, the g is superfluous as there can only be one substitution).
So the sed -n '/\<19\>/,+1p' cmfile|grep '38' is pointless as nothing is reading its output.
Also note that all of -i, +1, \<\> are non-standard GNU extensions², while the perl command will work on any system³.
Edit
With your updated requirements where you want to uncomment the lines where the first field contains 19 and the second contain 38 (themselves not surrounded by other digits):
perl -api -e 's/^\s*\K#// if $F[0] =~ /(?<!\d)19(?!\d)/ &&
                             $F[1] =~ /(?<!\d)38(?!\d)/' your-file

Here using the -awk mode there the fields are made available in the @F array or, if there may be whitespace on either side of the # which would result in the first field becoming the second field, do the full line matching with a regexp:
perl -pi -e 's/^\s*\K#(?=\s*\S*(?<!\d)19(?!\d)\S*\s+\S*(?<!\d)38(?!\d))//' your-file

Where we have (see perldoc perlrun, perldoc perlop and perldoc perlre for details):

-p: sed mode, where the -expression is evaluated for each line of input.
-i: in-place editing
s/regexp/replacement/: substitute the first match of the regular expression with replacement.
\s: any whitespace character, \S for non-whitespace.
<atom>*: the previous atom repeated any number of times including 0, as many as possible
\K: Keep what's on the left, or IOW resets the start of the match that will end up being substituted.
(?=...): positive look-ahead, or IOW "provided what follows matches ..."
(?<!...): negative look-behind, or IOW "provided what precedes does not match ..."
(?!...): negative look-ahead
\d: any decimal digit character. Without -C (for Unicode mode), that's limited to 0123456789.


¹ In any case, the 19 in pd19_ORA is not word-delimited as both d and _ are word characters; if you wanted to match on 19 that is neither preceded nor followed by a decimal digit, you'd use (?<!\d)19(?!\d) instead of \b19\b (the perl equivalent of ex' \<19\>).
² Well, strictly speaking, \<\> originated in ex/vi, not GNU sed and -i was copied by GNU sed from perl, and ,+1 from ed.
³ Though you'll need perl 5.10.0 (from 2007) or newer for \K (to Keep what's on the left of it). On systems will an older version of perl, you can replace s/^\s*\K#// with s/^(\s*)#/$1/.

is there any other alternatives other than perl?

@Kishan there are plenty alternatives to perl, but perl is the most obvious one for text processing. That's one of the things it is best at.

^# only matches # at the beginning of the line. One alternative to allow for whitespace before the comment is ^[ \t]*#
So, this line should work:
sed -n '/\<19\>/,+1p' cmfile|grep '38'|sed -i '/38/s/^\([ \t]*\)#/\1/g' cmfile


this works but removes the leading space

@Kishan Use a capture group and back-reference to copy the leading space to the output.

can you give some example?

It's fixed. The line above keeps the whitespace with a capture group and a back-reference as @barmar explained.
